# Replace double quotes using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on jQuery, I need to replace double quotes `"`.

This is what I have attempted:

```
var source="flower.jpg","boscket.jpg","cat.jpg";
```

I want to make it like this

```
var newstring=flower.jpg,boscket.jpg,cat.jpg;
```

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: `var source="flower.jpg","boscket.jpg","cat.jpg";` and `var newstring=flower.jpg,boscket.jpg,cat.jpg;` don't compile.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "inverted comma"?

Comment: do you really know why they were there...and some one marked this as favorites :)

Comment: I can't be sure as I don't understand the question but it looks more [JavaScript] than [jQuery].

Comment: i have this strings   strings="flower.jpg","boscket.jpg","cat.jpg";   i need to convert this strings as  newstring=flower.jpg,boscket.jpg,cat.jpg; it is possible

Comment: i need to make it split plz help me

Comment: What are you trying to do? Post more code...

Comment: Are you trying to join three strings in an array into a single string?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Please elaborate. Where does the strings come from, what will they be used for. More information quickly before your question will be closed due to poor quality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
var source='"flower.jpg","boscket.jpg","cat.jpg"';
var newstring = source.replace(/\"/g,'')
alert(newstring);
```

I'm assuming that **source** is a valid string wrapped in ''

Answer (score 0):

`var source="flower.jpg","boscket.jpg","cat.jpg";` will give n error

```
SyntaxError: missing variable name
```

you can do like

```
var source='"flower.jpg","boscket.jpg","cat.jpg"';
var newstring = source.replace(/\"/g,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably

```
var source="flower.jpg","boscket.jpg","cat.jpg";
```

is not valid javascript and can not be evaluated. I'll assume you have the following string instead:

```
var source='"flower.jpg","boscket.jpg","cat.jpg"';
```

To replace all the double quotes with nothing, use the following javascript (no jQuery needed):

```
source.replace(/"/g, '');
```

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace for more information on the string.replace method.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Here Example of replace single and double quata

```
jquery replace all single or double quotes

we can pass two parameter to replace single quotes in string

//replace all single quotes
var myStr = myStr.replace(/'/g, '');

//replace all double quotes
var myStr = myStr.replace(/"/g, '');

//or abit of fun, replace single quotes with double quotes
var myStr = myStr.replace(/'/g, '"');

//or vice versa, replace double quotes with single quotes
var myStr = myStr.replace(/"/g, ''');

jquery replace all single or double quotes
```

I can get reference from here [Replace double quotes using jQuery](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2016/11/jquery-replace-all-single-or-double.html)